# In sprintf warning message in PROCESS mediation analysis

Tags: r, mediation

I was trying to do mediation analysis in R with PROCESS and got the below warning. Can anyone please explain what this means if they have encountered it before? Does it affect the output of my analysis. Thanks.

Warning message:
In sprintf(decimals, stdmod, nrow(b) - 1) :
one argument not used by format '%9.4f'